# Maintain order after partition by key groupByKey or aggregateByKey

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have data like this

```
Machine , date , hours 
123,2014-06-15,15.4 
123,2014-06-16,20.3
123,2014-06-18,11.4 
131,2014-06-15,12.2 
131,2014-06-16,11.5
131,2014-06-17,18.2 
131,2014-06-18,19.2
134,2014-06-15,11.1
134,2014-06-16,16.2
```

I want to partition by key `Machine`, and find lag of hours by 1 default value 0

```
Machine , date , hours lag
123,2014-06-15,15.4,0
123,2014-06-16,20.3,15.4
123,2014-06-18,11.4,20.3
131,2014-06-15,12.2,0
131,2014-06-16,11.5,12.2
131,2014-06-17,18.2,11.5
131,2014-06-18,19.2,18.2
134,2014-06-15,11.1,0
134,2014-06-16,16.2,11.1
```

I am using `PairedRDD` and `groupByKey` method, but it doesn't yield in an expected order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is really no given order here. With some exceptions, RDDs should be considered unordered if any transformations you use require shuffling.

If you need specific order you have to sort your data manually:

```
case class Record(machine: Long, date: java.sql.Date, hours: Double)
case class RecordWithLag(
    machine: Long, date: java.sql.Date, hours: Double, lag: Double
)

def getLag(xs: Seq[Record]): Seq[RecordWithLag] = ???

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
    Record(123, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-15"), 15.4), 
    Record(123, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-16"), 20.3),
    Record(123, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-18"), 11.4), 
    Record(131, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-15"), 12.2), 
    Record(131, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-16"), 11.5),
    Record(131, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-17"), 18.2), 
    Record(131, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-18"), 19.2),
    Record(134, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-15"), 11.1),
    Record(134, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2014-06-16"), 16.2)
))

rdd
  .groupBy(_.machine)
  .mapValues(_.toSeq.sortWith((x, y) => x.date.compareTo(y.date) < 0))
  .mapValues(getLag)
```

For performance you should consider updating your Spark distribution to >= 1.4.0 and using a data frame with window functions:

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql(
  """"SELECT *, lag(hours, 1, 0) OVER (
        PARTITION BY machine ORDER BY date
      ) lag FROM df"""
)

+-------+----------+-----+----+
|machine|      date|hours| lag|
+-------+----------+-----+----+
|    123|2014-06-15| 15.4| 0.0|
|    123|2014-06-16| 20.3|15.4|
|    123|2014-06-18| 11.4|20.3|
|    131|2014-06-15| 12.2| 0.0|
|    131|2014-06-16| 11.5|12.2|
|    131|2014-06-17| 18.2|11.5|
|    131|2014-06-18| 19.2|18.2|
|    134|2014-06-15| 11.1| 0.0|
|    134|2014-06-16| 16.2|11.1|
+-------+----------+-----+----+
```

or

```
df.select(
  $"*",
  lag($"hours", 1, 0).over(
      Window.partitionBy($"machine").orderBy($"date")
  ).alias("lag")
)
```